# Reading keys and values when they are contained within the value of an existing field

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a extract which contains several JSON strings in the following format:

```
{'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2', 'automated': 'Not Automated', 'build': None, 'configurationId': 123, 
      'configurationName': 'Package 1.0', 'lastResultState': 1, 'lastRunBy': '', 'lastRunDuration': 0, 
      'mostRecentResultOutcome': 2, 'mostRecentRunId': 1234, 'outcome': 'Passed', 'state': 2, 
      'suiteId': 1234, 'suiteName': 'Name', 'testCaseId': 12345, 'testPointId': 12345, 'tester': 'Fred Smith', 
      'workItemProperties': [{'Key': 'System.Id', 'Value': 12345}, {'Key': 'System.Title', 'Value': 'Item Item'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.IterationPath', 'Value': 'Path\Path'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedDate', 'Value': '/Date(1554200489873)/'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedBy', 'Value': 'Fred Smith'}, 
                             {'Key': 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus', 'Value': 'Not Automated'}]}
```

I have been able to loop through these and display them in a Pandas DataFrame, appending each string as a new row, but I have run into a problem. I have a list of fields in my json string:

```
assignedTo
etc
workItemProperties < - this is the last field in the list
```

The last field 'workItemProperties' has the following as its value:

```
[{'Key': 'System.Id', 'Value': 12345}, {'Key': 'System.Title', 'Value': 'Item Item'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.IterationPath', 'Value': 'Path\Path'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedDate', 'Value': '/Date(1554200489873)/'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedBy', 'Value': 'Fred Smith'}, 
                             {'Key': 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus', 'Value': 'Not Automated'}]
```

I want to be able to display the fields held in that value in my table, so my field list would look like:

```
assignedTo
…
workItemProperties
System.Id
System.Title
System.IterationPath
Etc
```

Is it possible to get Pandas to pickup and recognise these 'child' fields and values from the value of workItemProperties? Or Will I have to do some sort of further string extraction/manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_normalize`

**Ex:**

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2', 'automated': 'Not Automated', 'build': None, 'configurationId': 123, 
      'configurationName': 'Package 1.0', 'lastResultState': 1, 'lastRunBy': '', 'lastRunDuration': 0, 
      'mostRecentResultOutcome': 2, 'mostRecentRunId': 1234, 'outcome': 'Passed', 'state': 2, 
      'suiteId': 1234, 'suiteName': 'Name', 'testCaseId': 12345, 'testPointId': 12345, 'tester': 'Fred Smith', 
      'workItemProperties': [{'Key': 'System.Id', 'Value': 12345}, {'Key': 'System.Title', 'Value': 'Item Item'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.IterationPath', 'Value': 'Path\Path'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedDate', 'Value': '/Date(1554200489873)/'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedBy', 'Value': 'Fred Smith'}, 
                             {'Key': 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus', 'Value': 'Not Automated'}]}


df = json_normalize(data, "workItemProperties", ['lastRunDuration', 'tester', 'testPointId', 'lastResultState', 'configurationId', 'mostRecentRunId', 'suiteName', 'state', 'testCaseId', 'assignedTo', 'configurationName', 'suiteId', 'build', 'mostRecentResultOutcome', 'automated', 'outcome', 'lastRunBy'])
df["workItemProperties"] = df.pop("Key")
df.drop(["Value"], inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   lastRunDuration  mostRecentResultOutcome      tester  configurationId  \
0                0                        2  Fred Smith              123   
1                0                        2  Fred Smith              123   
2                0                        2  Fred Smith              123   
3                0                        2  Fred Smith              123   
4                0                        2  Fred Smith              123   
5                0                        2  Fred Smith              123   

   mostRecentRunId suiteName  testCaseId  lastResultState  state  suiteId  \
0             1234      Name       12345                1      2     1234   
1             1234      Name       12345                1      2     1234   
2             1234      Name       12345                1      2     1234   
3             1234      Name       12345                1      2     1234   
4             1234      Name       12345                1      2     1234   
5             1234      Name       12345                1      2     1234   

  build  testPointId      automated configurationName outcome assignedTo  \
0  None        12345  Not Automated       Package 1.0  Passed   a5060ed2   
1  None        12345  Not Automated       Package 1.0  Passed   a5060ed2   
2  None        12345  Not Automated       Package 1.0  Passed   a5060ed2   
3  None        12345  Not Automated       Package 1.0  Passed   a5060ed2   
4  None        12345  Not Automated       Package 1.0  Passed   a5060ed2   
5  None        12345  Not Automated       Package 1.0  Passed   a5060ed2   

  lastRunBy                   workItemProperties  
0                                      System.Id  
1                                   System.Title  
2                           System.IterationPath  
3                             System.ChangedDate  
4                               System.ChangedBy  
5            Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus
```

Comment: [Link to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) I didn't know this existed, cool!

Comment: Really appreciate the response, thats definitely done the job. Is there anyway to only return the row that corresponds to System.Title? I tried ````df.loc['System.Title',:]``` but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rakesh Okay I think I am understanding it all a little better now, I actually don't want to drop the value column as that contains needed data, and I can get the specific line of data by doing ````df = df.loc[1,:]```` to get the System.Title value, or 4 for the System.ChangedDate value, my challenge now is that I need both but in one row, which I am not sure is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works perfectly, but another option someone suggested to me also works:

```
for item in df['workItemProperties']:
    key = item['Key']
    df[key] = item['Value']
del dfheader['workItemProperties']
table = pd.DataFrame(df,index=[0])
```

This completely flattens out the sub fields and values into columns with the rest of the data.